# Topic Challenge: LGBT Pride week [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

June is a [LGBT Pride Month](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gay_pride#LGBT_Pride_Month) and [due to popular opinion](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2835/1190) we're starting a new weekly topic challenge From 2017-06-26 08:00 UTC to 2017-07-03 07:59 UTC and we encourage you to ask questions from LGBT themed film/TV shows and questions on the subject of LGBT+ community from films and TV shows.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 11 and ~877 views) was asked by [BlueMoon93](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/32199/bluemoon93), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

1. [What was the first franchise to prominently feature LGBT characters?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75331/what-was-the-first-franchise-to-prominently-feature-lgbt-characters)

The other non closed questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Did the DCAU ever hint about Harley Quinn's bisexuality?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75566/did-the-dcau-ever-hint-about-harley-quinns-bisexuality) ( 4 / ~93)
3. [Why did Armand have to give Katherine money for custody rights to Val?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75550/why-did-armand-have-to-give-katherine-money-for-custody-rights-to-val) ( 3/ ~26)
4. [Is Hannibal Lecter in love with Will Graham?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/75445/is-hannibal-lecter-in-love-with-will-graham) ( 2 / ~74)