# Topic Challenge: Patrick Stewart and his films/TV shows [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

Today is [Patrick Stewart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrick_Stewart) birthday, so in honour of him and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2706/1190) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2017-07-13 16:00 UTC to 2017-07-20 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **Patrick Stewart and [the films/TV shows he was in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Patrick_Stewart,_roles_and_awards#Filmography)**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [patrick-stewart](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/patrick-stewart) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Comment: Time to watch Star Trek then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 27 and ~6,158 views) was asked by [Gustavo Gabriel](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/42976/gustavo-gabriel), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

1. [Why was Xavier losing control of his powers?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/76245/why-was-xavier-losing-control-of-his-powers)

The other non closed questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [How come Jason can stay safe when Professor X attacked mutants in X2?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/76494/how-come-jason-can-stay-safe-when-professor-x-attacked-mutants-in-x2) ( 8 / ~641)
3. [When Scrooge recognizes a boy named “Toby Veck”, is this a reference to someone?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/76397/when-scrooge-recognizes-a-boy-named-toby-veck-is-this-a-reference-to-someone) ( 7 / ~679)
4. [Who the hell is Amber?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/76613/who-the-hell-is-amber) ( 4 / ~43)
5. [How does the timeline of Logan fit into the X-Men universe?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/76317/how-does-the-timeline-of-logan-fit-into-the-x-men-universe) ( 0 / ~81)