# Topic Challenge: Stephen King [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

With the release of [*The Dark Tower*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1648190/) and due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2473/49) we're looking back on the rich history of Stephen King adaptations in a new **topic challenge. From 2017-08-08 00:00 UTC to 2017-08-18 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **films and TV-shows [based on Stephen King's works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adaptations_of_works_by_Stephen_King)**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Comment: where I can see the event/results before is closing?

Comment: Well, browse the questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 32 and ~4,596 views) was asked by [*steelersquirrel*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22792), which makes her the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Is the face on the front of the truck a Marvel approved likeness of the Green Goblin?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78505/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Why Top Hat reference was so necessary in The Green Mile?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78544/49) (7 / ~126)
3. [How was Pennywise's appearance in the novels when compared to film and miniseries?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78775/49) (6 / ~117)
4. [How did Andy get money to buy a rockhammer in The Shawshank Redemption?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78471/49) (5 / ~156)

   [Why is the mansion called "Rose Red"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78893/49) (5 / ~47)

   [What was with the hinted suicidal tendencies of Henry?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78653/49) (5 / ~31)

   [What is the significance of the painting at Rachel's parent's house?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78564/49) (5 / ~56)

   [Who has the rights to choose which ending to show?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78619/49) (5 / ~79)

   [What is the significance of making Eddie a hopeless virgin?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78898/49) (5 / ~66)

   [What were the creatures helping the Man in Black?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78506/49) (5 / ~68)
5. [Why did the werewolf kill an "innocent" victim?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78519/49) (3 / ~38)

   [What is the significance of "Beep Beep Richie!"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/78959/49) (3 / ~33)

Comment: YAY!  I was waiting for this challenge forever due to my love of Stephen King Adaptations!  I'm so happy that I won this challenge!   I would like to thank everyone who participated in this challenge with me.   It was super fun!   I'm glad that  this challenge introduced people to some awesome movies.   I was also excited that I used this challenge to get my boyfriend to finally watch  _The Green Mile_!  Thank you Stephen King for all of your awesome stories!  :)

Comment: @steelersquirrel You could accept my answer in that question then hahaha

Comment: @GustavoGabriel I usually wait for a few days after the challenge is over to accept answers that are worthy of acceptance.  Yours certainly was!  Accepted :)