# Topic Challenge: The TV-series of the Marvel Cinematic Universe [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

With the release of [The Defenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Defenders_(miniseries)) and due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1464/weekly-topic-challenge-ideas/3952#3952), we are starting a **new topic challenge. From 2017-08-26 07:00 UTC to 2017-09-02 07:00:00 UTC** we're challenging you to ask your great questions about [the TV-shows of the Marvel Cinematic Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Marvel_Cinematic_Universe_television_series).

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1464/weekly-topic-challenge-ideas) for new topics for our next possible challenge.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 4 and ~84 views) was asked by [*Ankit Sharma*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [How did Bakuto come back if the substance was already used up to resurrect Black Sky?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/79625/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Why does Luke appear in Jessica Jones and Jessica doesn't appear in Luke Cage?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/79630/49) (2 / ~183)
3. [Why did Danny Rand break the wall?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/79701/49) (0 / ~211)