# Topic Challenge: Philip K. Dick [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

The release of [*Blade Runner 2049*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1856101/) gives us a chance to look back on the rich history of [Philip K. Dick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Philip_K._Dick) adaptations, whose themes of reality and identity have always been a source for engaging films, kicked off by 1982's original [*Blade Runner*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0083658/). So due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2627/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2017-10-09 00:00 UTC to 2017-10-20 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **films and TV-shows [based on Philip K. Dick's works](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_adaptations_of_works_by_Philip_K._Dick)**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Comment: "we're challenging you to ______ all your great questions..."  I assume there should be an "ask" in there?

Comment: @JonathanvanClute Hmm, I don't think that's neccessary. Can't I challenge you to a noun? "I challenge you to your best behaviour!". "I challenge you to a game of wits!" I'm not a native speaker, though, so you could be right.

Comment: You're right, there are cases where that sounds perfectly normal to a native... "to a game of whits" is a perfect example.  But "to all your great questions" just made me stop and wonder - what about my great questions?  It just looked like a word was accidentally left out.  But who really knows... English rules are absolutely insane.  LOL  I'd categorize them more as suggestions than rules!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 30 and ~9,207 views) was asked by [*Ankit Sharma*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Is it necessary to watch the Blade Runner short films before Blade Runner 2049 to understand the story?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81258/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [What's the significance of Gaff's 2049 origami?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81444/49) (13 / ~1,658)
3. [Why are English, Russian, Japanese cultures emphasized in the Blade Runner 2049 world?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81423/49) (12 / ~3,282)

   [In Blade Runner 2049, why does Wallace do this?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81396/49) (12 / ~5,341)
4. [Why does Roy Batty die in 2019?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81493/49) (11 / ~1,324)

   [In Blade Runner 2049, whose eye opened in the first shot?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81485/49) (11 / ~855)
5. [What is the significance of bees in Blade Runner 2049?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81250/49) (10 / ~5,953)
6. [How did the term "skinjob" come about?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81580/49) (8 / ~124)
7. [What does Dr. Ana Stelline know in the movie Blade Runner 2049?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81350/49) (7 / ~2,353)
8. [Did K demonstrate autonomy, disobedience, and/or deception?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81525/49) (6 / ~128)

   [What does the dead tree symbolize in Blade Runner 2049?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81299/49) (6 / ~375)

   [In Blade Runner 2049, why does Deckard say Rachel had green eyes?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81712/49) (6 / ~534)
9. [What was the point of the first scene with Wallace and Luv?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81522/49) (5 / ~413)

   [Why is this character in a bubble?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81260/49) (5 / ~704)

   [Blade Runner 2049 What is baseline](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81588/49) (5 / ~1,356)
10. [Why didn't the bees sting Officer K's hand?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81283/49) (4 / ~201)

    [Why are they called Blade Runners? What does it mean?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81400/49) (4 / ~1,186)
11. [Blade Runner Photos Significance and photo from Rachael](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81508/49) (2 / ~98)

    [In Blade Runner 2049, what was going on in this scene?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81477/49) (2 / ~184)

    [Is there any significance of number 2049 in Blade Runner title?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81325/49) (2 / ~350)
12. [Are there allusions to Blade Runner in Alias?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81614/49) (1 / ~38)

    [How are the Nexus 9 models different?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81462/49) (1 / ~153)

    [Are glowing eyes of Replicants only meant for audience?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81496/49) (1 / ~62)

    [Why do K (and others) oppose Wallace?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81478/49) (1 / ~112)
13. [Must Wallace's replicants obey?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/81475/49) (0 / ~79)