# Halloween Topic Challenge: George A. Romero and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

Not only did this year see the death of horror pioneer [George A. Romero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_A._Romero), October was also the 49th anniversary of the release of his first movie *Night of the Living Dead*,  considered by many the first modern zombie movie, and together with its filmmaker one of the founding fathers of the entire genre. So befitting Halloween and due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2895/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2017-10-31 12:00 UTC to 2017-11-10 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **films and TV-shows [written or directed by George A. Romero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_A._Romero_filmography)**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question votes) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Comment: I suggested Romero/zombies last January (ahead of his February birthday) and my suggestion was deleted by Ankit. I honestly don't know *why* it was deleted from a thread about topic challenge suggestions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 7 and ~140 views) was asked by [*Nik-Lz*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/32997), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Why the shot of the Muslim Prayer in the opening credits scene?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/82518/49)

The other question asked, with a score of 4 and ~55 views, was:

2. [How much connected is the Night of the Living Dead film series?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/82526/49)

Comment: Actually a remake, but Wikipedia gives him writing credit.