# Topic Challenge: Leonardo DiCaprio and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

Today is [Leonardo DiCaprio's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo_DiCaprio) birthday, so in honour of him and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4027/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2017-11-11 00:00 UTC to 2017-11-19 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **Leonardo DiCaprio and [the films/TV shows he was in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leonardo_DiCaprio_filmography)**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [leonardo-dicaprio](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/leonardo-dicaprio) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 5 and ~56 views) was asked by [*Nog Shine*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/48608), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [What is the meaning of this patient's words to Teddy Daniels?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/82745/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [What was the meaning of Becky's conversation with mama?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/82726/49) (4 / ~35)
3. [What were the rats eating near the cave?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/82773/49) (3 / ~39)
4. [Is Katy Perry's song "The One That Got Away" homage to Titanic?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/82644/49) (2 / ~84)