# Topic Challenge: Rick Baker and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

Today is the birthday of Academy Award winner special effects and make-up artist [*Rick Baker*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_Baker). So in honour of him and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2819/1190) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2017-12-08 11:30 UTC to 2017-12-17 23:59 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **Rick Baker and [the films he did the special effects and make-up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rick_Baker#Filmography)**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [rick-baker](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/rick-baker) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Comment: Not to be confused with [Ricky Baker](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt4698684/characters/nm5421877?ref_=tt_cl_t2).

Comment: So...who won the challenge?   Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

he challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 52 and ~10,739 views) was asked by A J, which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Which worse thing was Luke expecting in Star Wars: A New Hope?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83620/1190)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Is there any significance to the Disney character figurines?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83471/1190) (10 / ~95)
3. [Why did filmmakers choose to make Sherman Klump morbidly obese?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83492/1190) (8 / ~90)
4. [Why was the scene with Biggs in A New Hope removed and never added again?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83708/1190) (6 / ~104)

   [What is the significance of shooting porn film for An American Werewolf in London?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83720/what-is-the-significance-of-shooting-porn-film-for-an-american-werewolf-in-londo) (6/ ~88)

   [Significance of Sergeant McManus's changing tie style?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/83772/significance-of-sergeant-mcmanuss-changing-tie-style)  (6 / ~47)
5. [What was the significance of the pentagram?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83822/1190) (5 / ~26)
6. [How did Newton survive after what happened to him in Men in Black 1?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83611/1190) (1 / ~94)

Comment: YAY!! I'd like to thank Ankit to bring me back and sponsoring this challenge. I'd also like to thank Mark Hamill to say that dialogue in that great movie. I'm also grateful to @Steelersquirrel for suggesting this ToW idea. And thanks to all who upvoted me. :D