# Topic Challenge: Christmas-themed films and TV episodes [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

In celebration of this most festive time of the year and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4069/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2017-12-18 00:00 UTC to 2017-12-24 23:59 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **Christmas-themed films and TV-show episodes**.

> Twas the week before Christmas, when all thro' the house
>   Not a creature was stirring, not even a mouse
>   But on Movies and TV everyone was in a flurry
>   Santa is on his way so you better well hurry

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 46 and ~9,419 views) was asked by [*Memor-X*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/4297), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Was The Nightmare Before Christmas meant to be a Halloween or Christmas Movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83854/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Why did Frank think that the waiter was Richard Pryor?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83879/49) (17 / ~3,066)
3. [Did "A Charlie Brown Christmas" cause controversy for CBS due to its religious content?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83840/49) (15 / ~203)
4. [What was Martian Manhunter singing in the end of Christmas special episode "Comfort and Joy"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83844/49) (10 / ~944)
5. [Why wasn't Rudolph included with Santa's reindeer?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/84036/49) (8 / ~233)
6. [What makes Die Hard a Christmas movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/84058/49) (6 / ~233)
7. [Is there a symbolic meaning behind the Spiral Hill in The Nightmare Before Christmas?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/84012/49) (3 / ~59)

   [Why are all of Mr. Shirley's gifts the same?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/84090/49) (3 / ~102)

   [How/why was the slow motion coin shot achieved in Scrooged?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83876/49) (3 / ~62)
8. [When and Where are all the Doctor Who Christmas Special set?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83913/49) (2 / ~52)

   [Is Dr. Mary Based or Inspired by Talk Show Radio Host, Dr. Laura?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83894/49) (2 / ~13)
9. [Can't they access cookie's memories directly or it was done for getting confession in White Christmas?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/83925/1190) (1/ ~58)