# Topic Challenge: Rockumentaries and Music Biopics [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

[Due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2642/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2018-02-12 00:00 UTC to 2018-02-23 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **rockumentaries and musician biopics, from real to fictional**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Comment: What does fictional mean? Do you mean a movie which is about musician who are writer's creation?

Comment: @NogShine Probably.

Comment: so fictional rock stars/musicians may be acceptable too, not just fictional works about real musicians and non fictional works about real musicians?

Comment: Yes, presumably.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 10 and ~76 views) was asked by [*steelersquirrel*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22792), which makes her the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Why was "A Hard Day's Night" filmed in black and white?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/85886/49)

The other question asked, with a score of 3 and ~107 views, was:

2. [Clear references in 'This Is Spinal Tap'](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/85729/49)

Comment: Thank you for sanpaco for proposing this challenge!  I wish that we would have had more participation, but any challenge that has a _This is Spinal Tap_ question, is fine by me :)