# Topic Challenge: Friday the 13th [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

In celebration of Friday the 13th of April 2018 and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2602/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2018-04-10 00:00 UTC to 2018-04-20 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about the **movies and TV-shows from the [*Friday the 13th* series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friday_the_13th_(franchise))**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 21 and ~5,780 views) was asked by [*steelersquirrel*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22792), which makes her the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Was Deborah Voorhees cast due to her surname?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/87965/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Why doesn't the regeneration power make the deformed face of Jason like before in Jason X?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/88109/49) (10 / ~1,613)
3. [Why was Whitney the prisoner of Jason Voorhees?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/87963/49) (8 / ~126)
4. [Why is the cut on the wrong side of Jason's hockey mask?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/88085/49) (7 / ~91)

   [How did they come up with the idea of using a hockey mask for Jason Voorhees?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/88138/49) (7 / ~189)
5. [Did Jason ever have the pattern of picking his target or was it always random?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/88200/49) (3 / ~78)
6. [What is the chronological order of Friday the 13th franchise?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/88042/49) (2 / ~99)

Comment: Acceptance Speech:  Thank you to Napoleon for FINALLY implementing this challenge ;)  Thank you to Ankit and AJ for participating along with me.  Thank you to my Father for creating me in the late 70's so that I could grow up watching these silly 80's slasher movies!! :P