# Topic Challenge: John Goodman and his films/TV shows [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

Today [John Goodman](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Goodman) turns 66 and can look back on an extensive career in film and television. So in honour of his life of acting and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2818/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2018-06-20 00:00 UTC to 2018-07-01 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **John Goodman and [the films/TV shows he was in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Goodman#Filmography)**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [john-goodman](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/john-goodman) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 11 and ~113 views) was asked by [*steelersquirrel*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/22792), which makes her the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Was The Dude wearing Donny's bowling shirt?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/89807/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Significance of the word Cloverfield](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/90007/49) (8 / ~1,135)
3. [What is the significance of cat's missing eye?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/89986/49) (6 / ~107)

Comment: Acceptance speech:  Thank you to John Goodman for choosing to be in awesome movies such as The Big Lebowski, Sea of Love, Raising Arizona, Always, The Emperor's New Groove, Monsters inc and many others and also for his role on Roseanne!  Thanks to Ankit for participating with me!  We.are.awesome! :P