# Topic Challenge: World War 1 [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

In commemoration of the 100th anniversary of the end of World War I and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4055/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2018-11-11 12:00 UTC to 2018-11-23 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **movies and TV-shows [involving World War I](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_World_War_I_films)**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Comment: How to participate?

Comment: @paul By...asking questions about the corresponding films.

Comment: I meant there is not specific that I need to attach with that question? That participants of this challenge would only attach.

Comment: @paul No, every question is eligible (and more often than not people aren't aware of the challenge when asking their question anyway). There's no special tags or anything beyond the normal question accessories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 5 and ~134 views) was asked by [*Ankit Sharma*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Impact of Wonder Woman's action on the end of World War I?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/94033/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Is Wonder Woman even a Wonder Woman in DC Extended Universe?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/94056/49) (4 / ~119)
3. [Why was Morgan/Ares pressurizing to negotiate peace?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/93983/49) (2 / ~92)