# Topic Challenge: Disney Animation Studios [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

With the release of [*Ralph Breaks the Internet*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt5848272/) and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2837/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2018-11-26 00:00 UTC to 2018-12-07 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **the wealth of [films made by Walt Disney Animation Studios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Walt_Disney_Animation_Studios_films)**<sup>1</sup>.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

[image]

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add a [disney](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/disney) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Comment: Liked the image part :)

Comment: Would a Q about optioning a sequel novel to a sequel animated film be considered a trivia question??

Comment: That depends on the question, which as of now I have no idea what that question would be.

Comment: I was thinking about asking if Disney ever considered adapting Dodie Smith's sequel novel to her The Hundred and One Dalmatians as a sequel to their 101 Dalmatians adaptation. The wiki page has some info towards the answer, but it sounds contradictory and so was going to ask if there was any other evidence...

Comment: That might make for a reasonable question, especially if you include why the existing sources are unsatisfying.

Comment: Cool I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 12 and ~5,489 views) was asked by [*Ankit Sharma*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Why did they pick the title 'Tangled'?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/94242/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Are the mermaids from The Little Mermaid intentionally modeled after/inspired by the mermaids in Peter Pan?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/94226/49) (8 / ~66)
3. [What led Disney Studios to release a film like Black Cauldron?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/94223/49) (6 / ~203)
4. [Disney's common theme of villainesses](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/94281/49) (4 / ~217)
5. [Why did Anna have to be shielded from all knowledge of magic?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/94423/49) (3 / ~115)

   [Did Disney ever consider adapting Dodie Smith's sequel to 101 Dalmations?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/94303/49) (3 / ~66)
6. [Why was Rapunzel with long hair?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/94442/49) (1 / ~104)

Comment: Congrats, Anik Sharma!!:)