# Topic Challenge: Aviation [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

In celebration of [Wright Brothers Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wright_Brothers_Day) and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2910/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2018-12-17 12:00 UTC to 2018-12-28 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **films and TV-shows involving aviation**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Comment: Well, I guess this is a good excuse as ever to rewatch The Aviator. Manic & paranoid Howard Hughes, here I come!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There really wasn't much of a rush to this topic challenge and the only and thus top-voted question (with a score of 24 and ~4,246 views), albeit a strongly aviation-related one, was asked by [*BruceWayne*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/29308), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Crop duster to F/A-18 Pilot - how feasible?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/95784/49)

Comment: Congrats!! I couldn't think of anything that wasn't already asked!!

Comment: Very less participation, maybe blame winterbash