# Topic Challenge: Anthony Hopkins and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

Today not only the current year ends but also [Sir Anthony Hopkins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Hopkins) turns 81 and can look back on an extensive acting career. So in honour of his life of acting and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4369/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2018-12-31 12:00 UTC to 2019-01-11 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **Anthony Hopkins and [the films he was in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthony_Hopkins_filmography)**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add an [anthony-hopkins](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anthony-hopkins) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Comment: "Goodie, Goodie!"

Comment: "Oh Shit!!!" My reaction on seeing this post thinking Sir Hopkins died & you guys are doing this as a remembrance.

Comment: @KharoBangdo most of the ToW is for birthday or new film

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 2 and ~159 views) was asked by [*Darth Locke*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/56522), which makes them the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Is Westworld intentionally referencing Hannibal Lecter?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/96051/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [Did Anthony Hopkins need to do any prep work for Hannibal?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/96050/49) (2 / ~54)
3. [What does the Russian soldier say to Sarah Ross while she is pretending to be a guard in the Kremlin?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/96029/49) (1 / ~59)
4. [Is there some reconciliation of how death of this character is handled beyond the end of the movie?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/96278/49) (0 / ~82)
5. [Is Dr. Ford's dialogue referencing The Prestige?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/96137/49) (-2 ~75)

Comment: A winner on a Q that I think not too many liked, but I will take what I can get! It was fun challenge! :p

Comment: It was my first time participating in a challenge of this sort on the site. https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/96064/what-kind-of-preparation-is-done-on-set-when-an-actor-has-to-play-a-character-in Why wasn't this question considered. How's it not related to the topic

Comment: @KharoBangdo It seems to be a more general question. But the pactical truth is...I simply missed it for exactly that reason. I don't really check every single question. I primarily go by tags and titles.