# Topic Challenge: Toys [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

With the release of [*Toy Story* 4](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1979376/) and [*Child's Play*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt8663516/) and due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4499/48608), we're back with a new **topic challenge**. **From 2019-06-22 00:00 UTC to 2019-06-30 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to ask your questions about **all movies where toys are a central theme**.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/48608) for our next possible challenge.

Comment: just from the title, this sounded very dirty ;)

Comment: @Visha With the challenge inspired by children's toys, this says more about you than the title, though. ;-)

Comment: It only sounds dirty because children's toys quite regularly are dirty ... I mean, they could use a good cleaning ... all them germs ... nasty things I tell yah. Where's the Lysol when you need it? Argh ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The challenge is over and the only and thus top-voted question (with a score of 9 and ~185 views) was asked by [*Snack_Food_Termite*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/75059), which makes them the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [Did the movie "Small Soldiers" produce any spin off toys?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/101794/49)

Answer (score 2):

I've changed my handle which is a little weird. But anyway thank you very much! The movie "Small Soldiers" also deserved it! Archer and Chip Hazard have sent me their congratulations! I was surprised; there were many movies with toys such as Chucky in child's play and TV shows like Wonderwoman had the Toy Maker. I expected someone else to post!