# Topic Challenge: Moon Landings and Space Exploration [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

In celebration of half a century of [humanity colonizing the known universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apollo_11) and due to [popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4528/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2019-07-20 00:00 UTC to 2019-07-30 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **space exploration and the moon landings in particular in film and TV**, be it documentary coverage, historical fiction or even semi-realistic speculation.

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 49 and ~9198 views) was asked by [*A J*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/27264), which makes him the winner of this challenge by virtue of HNQ and *just enough* skirting of the "realistic space exploration" line with his film ;-)

## 1. [Why are there not any MRI machines available in Interstellar?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/102265/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [How much did NASA help with the making of "First Man"?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/102234/49) (5 / ~350)
3. [Why does Mark say he hasn't had a shower for a year and a half?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/102319/49) (2 / ~188)
4. [Why does Mark lose so much weight in the end?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/102318/49) (2 / ~117)

Comment: Hehe! I didn't expect that response. :D Thanks to Nolan for this great film, thanks to Snow for proposing this challenge, and thank you for implementing it. (FYI, you forgot to write the congratulatory comment under my question.)

Comment: Nice.  Glad a few questions were asked - I was starting to worry for a bit.