# Topic Challenge: Irrfan Khan and his films [completed]

Tags: discussion, scheduled-event, challenge

Last week saw the death of [Irrfan Khan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrfan_Khan) who not only made himself a big name in Indian cinema but also ventured into international productions. So in honour of his life of acting and [due to popular demand](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4666/49) we're starting a new **topic challenge. From 2020-05-02 00:00 UTC to 2020-05-10 23:00 UTC** we're challenging you to all your great questions about **Irrfan Khan and [the films and TV-shows he was in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irrfan_Khan_filmography)**.<sup>1</sup>

Once the challenge is over, we'll tally the results and winners (by question score) here. Also don't forget to [suggest and vote for new topics](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49) for our next possible challenge.

---

1) <sub>But don't feel compelled to add an [irrfan-khan](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/irrfan-khan) tag to each and every of those questions, tag responsibly instead.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The challenge is over and the top-voted question (with a score of 6 and ~386 views) was asked by [*Ankit Sharma*](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190), which makes him the winner of this challenge:

## 1. [What role was Irrfan Khan supposed to play?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/109075/49)

The other questions asked, in order of votes are (the numbers are the votes and views):

2. [What was the significance of overemphasis of conservation of resources posters?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/109073/49) (1 / ~9)
3. [What was Dev's obsession with other people's wife picture while self pleasure?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/109074/49) (0 / ~13)