# Should Movies & TV Meta have obituary posts for deaths of famous cineasts, similar to what Sci Fi and Fantasy does?

Tags: discussion

Sci-Fi and Fantasy have [Meta posts](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/in-memoriam) that get added to the front page when people with significance for the genre die, like actors, writers, directors, voice actors, reviewers, and other significant people. They're essentially obituaries with a more relaxed mood, where people can reminisce about the deceased and their career. I wonder if Movies and TV should do the same on their meta for famous cineasts, like the recently deceased Roger Mosley.

Answer (score 10):

To be honest, **no, I don't think we should**. Sorry to be the spoilsport here, but I really don't think the meta site is a place for such things since they have **absolutely nothing to do with the workings of this site** and are just random news posts. It feels like **using meta as a dumping ground for things that are off-topic** on the main site, which it really is not. I've never been a fan of these on SciFi. It's their site and they kind of like them, but I'm glad this isn't done here. I understand the desire to have a place for reminiscing about departed idols, but at the end of the day a Q&A site unfortunately can't serve every need of a less information-oriented film aficionado community. And trying to press it into the meta site just because you can't find any other place, is really only dilluting that.

In fact, for informal stuff like that there is actually a place: **chat, which doesn't have these strict limits** of topicality and purpose as the main and meta sites. Feel free to **pop into [our main chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1888/the-screening-room) and bemourn our lost idols**. We actually often post news about dead celebrities from the film world and sometimes they lead to interesting discussions about the departed and their work.

Another much more appropriate and fruitful way to bemourn people and their contribution to the world of films and TV is also a **[topic challenge](https://movies.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1464/49)**. In the past we often did topic challenges for deceased actors and directors and their work. Although, the topic challenges have fallen asleep a little lately, suggesting one is still possible and would be a **much better way to reminisce about the impact these people had on the world and our lives within the confines of a Q&A site**.